# gltf-js-utils set texture in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gltf

Is it possible to set texture in https://github.com/wnayes/glTF-js-utils when you use node?
I see only HTMLImageElement can be applied there https://github.com/wnayes/glTF-js-utils/blob/4d1057981c0e0444fde854754ea57040614bd24b/dist/gltfjsutils.d.ts#L161

```
type TextureImageType = HTMLImageElement | HTMLCanvasElement;
    export class Texture {
        wrapS: WrappingMode;
        wrapT: WrappingMode;
        private __image;
        set image(val: TextureImageType);
        get image(): TextureImageType;
        constructor(image: TextureImageType);
    }
```

But how to do in node.js, where HTMLElement not available?

Answer (score 1):

You could try giving it a [node-canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas) instance instead, but it looks like this library was designed to be used on the web and not in Node.js, so there may be other limitations like this. It may be best to report a feature request to the project.